# Excel: processing data using formulas

Tags: excel, formula

I have a task to get and process some data from table using Excel formulas.
Table looks like this:

```
  A          B      C      D
  Date       Name   Count  Job
1 11.11.2020 Adam   260    1
2 12.11.2020 Nikole 300    2
3 11.11.2020 Adam   900    1
4 11.11.2020 Mary   750    1
```

What's the task is:

1. I have field with data and job number. For example, in `A1` I have `11.11.2020`, in `A2` I have `1`. First of all, I need to get all rows by these conditions. In example there would be first, third and fourth rows.
2. After that I need to group my results by name and sum `Count` field. In the example I would get Adam - 1160, Mary - 750.
3. Then I need to check each result: if the result is `<1000`, the name gets `30`, if `>=1000 and <1500` - `60`, if `>=1500` - `90`. In our example Adam gets `60` and Mary `30`.
4. After that I have to sum these numbers and write them to cell with formula. For the example answer would be `90`.

Now I am solving this problem using macro with SQL-query:

```
SELECT Name, SUM(Count) FROM MyTable WHERE Date = "A1" AND Job = "A2" GROUP BY Name
```

Then I loop through query result and write results of `SumOfCount` in the array, and write sum of it into my cell.

But this way is too long, because `MyTable` has more than 500.000 rows and the query inside macro is running too slow.

I am loosing one another more simple problem using `SUMIFS`; for example, then I need to sum only `Count` values I would use this:

```
=SUMIFS(MyTable!$C:$C; MyTable!$A:$A; $A1; MyTable!$D:$D; $A2)
```

Is there any way to solve my problem using Excel formula? Maybe there is any way to write my own formula-function for counting my values?

Comment: What will be your output. Show in post.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if a formula-based solution would be faster (especially if it has to work over 500000 rows). Try this subroutine:

```
Sub SubElaborateTable()
    
    'Declarations.
    Dim RngSource As Range
    Dim RngResult As Range
    Dim RngRange01 As Range
    Dim RngTarget As Range
    Dim DatDate As Date
    Dim DblJob As Double
    Dim WksPivotTableWorksheet As Worksheet
    Dim PvtPivotTable As PivotTable
    
    'Setting variables.
    Set RngSource = Sheets("MyTable").Range("A:D")
    Set RngResult = Sheets("MyTable").Range("F1")
    
    'Adding a new sheet.
    Set WksPivotTableWorksheet = Sheets.Add
    
    'Creating a pivot table out of RngSource.
    Set PvtPivotTable = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
                                                          SourceData:=RngSource, _
                                                          Version:=6 _
                                                         ).CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=WksPivotTableWorksheet.Cells(1, 1), _
                                                                            TableName:=WksPivotTableWorksheet.Name & " Pivot Table", _
                                                                            DefaultVersion:=6 _
                                                                           )
    
    'Filling and formatting the pivot table.
    With PvtPivotTable
        With .PivotFields("Date")
            .Orientation = xlRowField
            .Position = 1
            .PivotItems("(blank)").Visible = False
        End With
        With .PivotFields("Job")
            .Orientation = xlRowField
            .Position = 2
        End With
        With .PivotFields("Name")
            .Orientation = xlRowField
            .Position = 3
        End With
        .AddDataField .PivotFields("Count"), "Count sum", xlSum
        .ColumnGrand = False
        .RowGrand = False
        .PivotFields("Date").Subtotals = Array(False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False)
        .PivotFields("Job").Subtotals = Array(False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False)
    End With
    
    'Setting RngRange01.
    With WksPivotTableWorksheet
        Set RngRange01 = .Range(Cells(2, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
    End With
    
    'Filling the result headers.
    RngResult.Value = "Date"
    RngResult.Offset(0, 1).Value = "Job"
    RngResult.Offset(0, 2).Value = "Score"
    
    'Covering the whole RngRange01.
    For Each RngTarget In RngRange01
        
        'Setting DatDate or DblJob according to RngTarget value.
        Select Case True
            Case Is = IsDate(RngTarget.Value)
                DatDate = RngTarget.Value
            Case Is = IsNumeric(RngTarget.Value)
                DblJob = RngTarget.Value
        End Select
        
        'Checking if a Count value is encountered.
        If RngTarget.Offset(0, 1).Value <> "" Then
            
            'If the actual RngResult refers to a different date or job, RngResult is set on the next row.
            If RngResult.Value <> DatDate Or RngResult.Offset(0, 1).Value <> DblJob Then
                Set RngResult = RngResult.Offset(1, 0)
            End If
            
            'Filling in the results accordingly.
            RngResult.Value = DatDate
            RngResult.Offset(0, 1).Value = DblJob
            Select Case RngTarget.Offset(0, 1).Value
                Case Is < 1000
                    RngResult.Offset(0, 2).Value = RngResult.Offset(0, 2).Value + 30
                Case Is < 1500
                    RngResult.Offset(0, 2).Value = RngResult.Offset(0, 2).Value + 60
                Case Is >= 1500
                    RngResult.Offset(0, 2).Value = RngResult.Offset(0, 2).Value + 90
            End Select
            
        End If
        
    Next
    
    'Deleting WksPivotTableWorksheet.
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    WksPivotTableWorksheet.Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    
End Sub
```